# RangeX in geoviews, trying to understand x axis range

Tags: python, holoviews, geoviews

Can someone please explain to me the meaning of the x axis range retrieved using RangeX for geospatial data?

```
import geoviews as gv
import holoviews as hv

background = gv.tile_sources.Wikipedia
rng = hv.streams.RangeX(source=background)
background
```

[image]

When I call the rng object I do get None at first for `x_range` and upon using the wheel zoom, I do get following output:

```
rng
RangeX(x_range=(-18473547.316975493, 15590216.865764225))
```

I would expect `(-170, 149)`  but not roughly 1e5 times that value. How can I interpret the output from `RangeX` in that case?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles upon this noob question. The reason lies in different coordinate systems. It is necessary to transform the coordinate system from WGS84 (https://epsg.io/3857) to Mercator (https://epsg.io/4326). This can be done like:

```
from pyproj import Transformer
transformer = Transformer.from_crs(3857, 4326)
ran = transformer.transform(rng.x_range[0], rng.y_range[0])
```

EDIT:

I found that using the holoviews utility function a bit easier but the results are the same. Also it is necessary to provide (x, y) pairs to the functions in order to get the correct results. Not only x values.

```
hv.util.transform.easting_northing_to_lon_lat(x_range[0], y_range[0])
```

Comment: That's correct; the underlying objects being displayed by Bokeh are in Web Mercator coordinates (meters), and those are also what would normally get displayed as the axis labels except that tile sources helpfully convert those values back to a form humans will understand. RangeX provides the raw values from the actual display, and you can use pyproj or the https://holoviews.org/reference_manual/holoviews.util.html#holoviews.util.transform.easting_northing_to_lon_lat function in holoviews to convert them back to lat/lon.